# google maps get sender element in click event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the element let say marker when it is clicked. Mouse click event not send any object of sender.
I know this can be achieved via :

```
var locMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map : map,
            icon : icon,
            position : point
        });

        locMarker.id = (i + 1);
        locMarker.clubID = clubid;
        locMarker.clubName = clubname;

        google.maps.event.addListener(locMarker, 'click', function(evt) {
            console.log(evt);
            console.log(locMarker);
        });
```

But this way I can only get `evt`, not the whole marker object, here i can access marker object, but if i declare click event function somewhere else like this :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(locMarker, 'click', this.locationMarkerOnClick);
```

then i only get `evt`, not markerObject. Is there any solution?

Comment: you are try to getting? what my i know exact problem...

Comment: I want to get `locMarker` object in my case

Comment: do you mean ,you want to get the marker on the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the keyword `this`:

```
    (function() {
        var locMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            position: point
        });

        locMarker.id = (i + 1);
        locMarker.clubID = clubid;
        locMarker.clubName = clubname;

        google.maps.event.addListener(locMarker, 'click', this.locationMarkerOnClick);

    })();

    function locationMarkerOnClick(evt) {
        console.log(this); // get (show in console) the marker itself
        console.log(evt); // show the evt as expected
    }
```

Comment: Oh, i totally forgot that.

Comment: This won't work with arrow function in a callback. Is there any other ways?